# One-sided derivatives clarification

Tags: derivatives

A year ago we learnt left hand and right hand derivatives, $f'_{-}(a), f'_{+}(a)$ and the definitions were
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \text{and} \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
respectively.
Now, relearning this, my notes specified the *one-sided* deriviatves $D^{+}f(a)$ and $D^{-}f(a)$ as
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a+)}{h} \text{and} \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a-)}{h}$$.
I don't see the big picture here, and it even said that
$D^{\pm}f(a)$ is not necessarily the same as $f'(a\pm)$.
Is there much significance in that latter derivatives?
Context: Learning piecewise differentiable functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe $D^{\pm} f $ are defined for noncontinuous function where "$a+$" and "$a-$" may be different.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there a more "standard" name for these derivatives then (to distinguish my two sets of definitions). I want to find out more in depth, but it seems that when I search "one-sided" derivatives, only my first set of definitions pop up.

Comment: Yeah, I'm too not familiar with the second definition you gave. It seems not really important because most of the time people don't talk about these 'one sided' derivatives.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm not too worried now, (so I'll just remember it for the test) but I thought there would be more motivation behind this, what a shame